# How to use password protected webservice in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

i am consuming a webservice which is password protected, i have user name and password with me to access that webservice, how to implement it into Angular 7.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ImageService {

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
userName: String = "Xyz";
password: String = "yOsadfsdasV";
domain: String = "DIR";
getImage(imageUrl: string): Observable {
const headers = new HttpHeaders(

  {

    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + btoa(`${this.userName}:${this.password}:${this.domain}`)

  });    

return this.httpClient.get(imageUrl, {headers: headers,  responseType: 'blob' });
}
}
```

in above code imageUrl is URL of my webservice, problem with this code is i am getting below popup:

[image]

what is wrong in above code? or what needs to be add? Please help. I am doing in angular 7.
Thanks.

Comment: Nothing your doing seems necessarily wrong.  Without knowing more details about how the server is configured to accept authentication it is hard to say. The only thing that seems odd is the domain in your `Authorization` header.  With basic authentication there is usually only the username and password.

Comment: i removed domain and passed authentication in body and able to execute service but now getting output in Content-Type: application/octet-stream this format so not able to bind into image src.
this service is returning an image and i have to bind it to in my Image .

Comment: You might be able to influence the response type by using the appropriate `Accept` header but that seems pretty unlikely. If the server is sending back `application/octet-stream` then they should have additional information in their API documentation or some other resource telling you how to interpret those bytes (e.g. are they a PNG image? BMP? JPG?)